# C program, lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I write a program but while assigning the value after  making a condition it shows a error called "lvaluered as left operand of assignment". How to solve this error?

My code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int calls;
float bills;

printf("Enter the number of calls:\n");
scanf("%d",&calls);

calls<=100? bills=250:bills=250+(1.25*(calls-100));

printf("Bills: %f Rs.",bills);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't abuse the ternary/conditional operator like that; it leads to bugs!  (Some of them don't compile — others do.  The ones that compile are a bigger problem than those that don't!)

Answer (score 4):

You could write this much more clearly as either

```
bills = calls<=100 ? 250 : 250 + (1.25*(calls-100));
```

or

```
if(calls <= 100)
     bills = 250;
else bills = 250 + (1.25*(calls-100));
```

or even

```
bills = 250;
if(calls > 100)
     bills += 1.25*(calls-100);
```

(Me, I would go with this last one.)

Comment: `bills = 125 + 1.25 * max(calls, 100);` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `()` around the third operand:

```
calls<=100? bills=250:(bills=250+(1.25*(calls-100)));
```

Otherwise it's parsed as:

```
(calls<=100? bills=250:bills)=250+(1.25*(calls-100));
```

---

The second line, while doing the wrong thing, would compile in C++. But in C, the result of `?:` seems to always be an rvalue and can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the error message is misleading in this case. What you wrote in your code is syntactically nonsensical. This sequence of tokens

```
calls<=100? bills=250:bills=250+(1.25*(calls-100));
```

has ho valid parses in standard C grammar. It is a syntactic error.

Guessing your intent, to make it parse you'd need

```
calls <= 100 ? (bills = 250) : (bills = 250+(1.25*(calls-100)));
```

However, a more elegant and meaningful application of `?:` operator in this case would be

```
bills = calls <= 100 ? 250 : 250+(1.25*(calls-100));
```

---

The C compiler you are using uses "non-standard" version of C grammar, which makes it parse your original expression as

```
(calls<=100? bills=250:bills) = (250+(1.25*(calls-100)));
```

which is indeed an attempt to assign something to an non-lvalue.